# Prisma FindMany input type

Tags: typescript, prisma

Hi I am currently using prisma 2 to query a database by using the `findMany` Method, example of how I do this is here

```
const data = await prisma.user.findMany({
    take: 10000,

    select: {
      A: {
        select: {
          B: true,
          C: true,
          D: true,
        },
      },
    }
}
```

I would like to implement it where I can define the object that this `findMany` takes externally, like

```
const obj = {
    take: 10000,

    select: {
      A: {
        select: {
          B: true,
          C: true,
          D: true,
        },
      }
    }

const data = await prisma.user.findMany(obj)
```

However I am having an issue as to getting the type for `obj`, hovering over the `findMany` function, it tells me that the type it takes is of type `UserFindManyArgs` however I cant seem to find a way to import this.
Any advice on how to do this will be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can find these types under the Prisma namespace. So this should work:

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

type T = Prisma.UserFindManyArgs
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `User` prefix is generated from the table name and the middle part `FindMany` is the type of query you want to perform. If you want to look at other types generated for your database look for the `index.d.ts` file in the `node_modules/.prisma/client` folder. This file contains types not only for query methods but for table rows also.